# Copy table and paste it in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the only table on one worksheet (PRODUCT), then paste it to another sheet (TERMSHEET). I've third recording, searching in the internet but cannot find anything that works. The table is in range (A60:C66) and need to paste it in range (A108:B116).

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried and let us know where was your code going wrong. A sample screen prints/sample test data can help a lot

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
sheets("PRODUCT").range("A60:C66").copy sheets("TERMSHEET").range("A108")
```